# Why did this audit fail?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

In this particular case, I completely and honestly do not understand. Got a "STOP! Look and Listen", but why?

The audit is here -> https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/5214580

The category is "Reopen Votes". I vote for "Leave Closed" where the question is solved by OP itself, and the only difference is a small explanation. Why should this question be reopened, since it already has been closed as low quality, unclear or whatever, after it has been solved by OP himself?

I cannot see the logic. For one, punish me for leaving the question closed, second, for punishing the community that now have yet another self-answered low-activity question without any real answers to deal with.

Why should this question be reopened? And why use this as a test case anyway? I really fail to see the big picture.

And again :

https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/5215291

Here I voted for "Leave Closed", it was wrong too : You seem to be right @Andrew Medico. If it is an upvoted question, to 5 or more, it is a fail not to reopen, regardless the content or quality.

[image]

Comment: The only thing we can do is close it now with the reason: No longer reproduceable. That will remove it as an audit candidate for the reopen queue I guess.

Comment: Look like a mod is taking care of it...

Comment: @rene, I would really like to hear an explanation. I am not offended or "angry", just baffled.

Comment: Oh, thank goodness, I'm not the only person who extracts the answer from a question and posts it as a community wiki.

Comment: It had 7 upvotes when I arrived at that question and one deleted answer. Questions with a positive score are considered answerable and thus should remain open the system argues. It doesn't take the actual content into account when choosing it as an audit candidate @davidkonrad

Comment: "Reopen" audits are automatically selected from the set of questions that are unanimously upvoted (no downvotes), so sometimes low-quality but upvoted questions get used as audits. You can detect these by noticing when you get a review for a question with a relatively high number of upvotes (more than 5 or so) - open the question in a new tab, check if it actually has any close votes and check its up/down vote count. When you identify an audit, you can downvote it if you don't agree, skip, or vote to leave open.

Comment: @rene, thank you, but somehow it sounds mysterious. So I should vote for reopening just because a question has a plus score? "Does not compute" to me :)

Comment: @AndrewMedico, this was a good "trick", thank you. Have never felt it nessecary or thought about it was nessecary to "review the reviews", but maybe it is. Normally I pass through those occasionally tests, and normally I understand why, if I dont, but in this case I dont see the logic.

Comment: @AndrewMedico, you are apperently right about just reopening questions which have gained 5 or more in upvote. Sad to say.