# I've got "Review audit failed" unreasonably for selecting "Leave Closed" to a question with no changes made at all

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, reopen-closed

Concerning reviewing this **https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/11224658** I got **Review audit failed**:

> #### **STOP! Look and Listen.**
>
> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. **You didn't pass**. There are no major problems with this question. You should click Reopen, or make minor corrections via Edit and Reopen.
>   Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately – but please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the guidance above.

That is a long post and it was closed as "**`Unclear what you're asking`**" even though there were *zero indications* that the question has been changed *at all* (*no light-greenish areas like* [image]).

My question is, if it was supposedly <sup>(**1**)</sup> closed for the mentioned reason above and it has *NOT* changed after closing it, how am I supposed to vote for re-opening it, I usually vote to reopen when there're meaningful changes but as I said there were absolutely no changes not even one character or image or even a blank space?

I've already read those posts and it seems like it's not only me:

- [Failed Reopen Vote Queue Audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296576/failed-reopen-vote-queue-audit)
- [Wrong question used for Audit in Reopen queue?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310037/wrong-question-used-for-audit-in-reopen-queue)
- [I failed a reopen-vote audit which only had minor improvements](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293721/i-failed-a-reopen-vote-audit-which-only-had-minor-improvements)
- [Why did this audit fail?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262524/why-did-this-audit-fail)

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<sup>(**1**)</sup>  I said supposedly because [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35141376/observable-linq-inconsistent-exceptions-thrown) is not really closed.

Comment: Lol, Thanks for the downvote, still I'd like to know the answer of my question @thePersonWhoDownVoted

Comment: Sometimes questions has been closed incorrectly (there is actually no reason to close them). Because of that it is perfectly OK to vote-for-reopen even **without changes in the question post**. When you review such *manual* (as opposite to automatic, like after editing of the post) reopen votes, you need to *check entire post*. Audit for reopen queue just triggers such situation.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev for the response and hmmm that sounds kind of reasonable, thanks again

Comment: Hmm, that would have been a hard one for me, too. Doesn't look like a very high quality question. I might not have voted to close it in the first place because I'm not comfortable enough with my knowledge in the domain area, but I certainly wouldn't have nominated it for re-opening, assuming that it had already been closed by 5 community members. Another stupid audit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sometimes questions have been closed incorrectly (there is actually no reason to close them). Because of that it is perfectly OK to vote-for-reopen even **without changes in the question post**.

While reviewing such *manual* reopen votes you need to **check entire post**.

The reopen queue audit you failed just triggers such situation.

---

In my practice, when I find a question closed incorrectly, I prefer to leave comment explaining my reopen vote, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995936/how-to-link-a-third-party-library-libusb-in-cmake#comment57730166_34995936). So, when reviewing manual reopen votes, it could be useful to **look into comments**. [Though checking the comments is useful during of reviewing of any type.]

Comment: If after checking entire question post you think that the question should be reopened, then voting for reopen is OK. Getting `STOP! Look and Listen` in that case means that **audit itself is bad**: it chooses *controlversal* question. BTW, [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262524/why-did-this-audit-fail) you link also describes the situation, when audit itself is bad.

Comment: Yup, I've already read that post and I have it in my question -*the last link*- as well as this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296576/failed-reopen-vote-queue-audit from [Mohit Jain](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2659313/mohit-jain) answer "*`These audits are automatic and the heuristics highly rely on the vote count`*", I just asked to have some *guidelines* about it because sometimes it sounds meaningless